# Can SSRS support multi-tenant usage?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, multi-tenant

I have a webforms application built on top of the standard microsoft stack - asp.net, sqlserver2008, ssis, ssrs.  In certain cases I would like to run this entire stack in a multi-tenant type mode such that users of one 'slice' would not have any visibility to others.

We've solved this on the webapp and ssis side, but not yet with Sql Server Reporting Services.

Is there a way on a single machine, with a single instance of Sql Server 2008, to carve out multiple logical reporting services "sites"?  I need to be able to configure reports, security, and data sources separately for each slice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Still evaluating to see if this does in fact do what I need it to; however, this blog post does seem promising......

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2006/12/18/multiple-reporting-services-instances-on-one-machine.aspx